# To compare n number of fields in Kibana

Tags: kibana

Is there a way to compare two or more fields,as per requirement in Kibana?. Each document consists only 10 fields and the index consisits of only 50 documents. So is there a simple way to compare two or more fields?

Comment: What have you done/tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand,you need a way,so that you could see all the fields and make random comparisons between fields. Kibana offers one such simple feature. This can be done by creating a new panel inside a row and selecting the panel type "table". This lists all your fields in the left side with selection checkboxes and then you can select any of them. On selection,the field details would get added as new coloumns to the right as show below. 
[image]

A more detailed guide on how to use the above feature can be found in this [blog](http://blog.qbox.io/tutorial-simple-analysis-using-kibana)